# Подсчитать количество одинаковых элементов в массиве

Tags: php, html

есть таблица files в БД Mysql
поле - id
поле - section

есть 5 файлов
id=1 section=maps
id=2 section=maps
id=3 section=weapons
id=4 section=weapons
id=5 section=weapons

при выходе должно получится
maps-2
weapons-3

мной написанный код почему-то не работает, выдает ошибку, помогите её исправить, где я допустил её???

```
<?php 
require_once ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/database.php");

$count = 0;
$array = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT section FROM files WHERE game='1' GROUP BY section");
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $array[$count] = $row;
        $count++;
    }
    $new_Array = array_count_values($array);
    foreach ($new_Array as $section=> $sum) {
        echo "$section ($sum)<br/>";
    }
}
else {
    echo 'Файлов нет!';
}
?>
```

Comment: > выдает ошибку

какую?

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает? Местные телепаты в замешательстве.

Comment: Да ладно - телепаты отлично все видят.

    $array[$count] = $row["section"];

Но это так, чтобы код работал. А чтобы он свою задуманную автором функцию выполнял - нужно запрос исправить.

Comment: > Но это так, чтобы код работал

а какие проблемы у php были в помещении $row в массив $array по индексу? проблемы дальше возникают, когда пытаемся вывести массив $row (он уже $sum) через echo.

Comment: `array_count_values` 

    Генерирует ошибку уровня E_WARNING для каждого элемента, не являющегося string или integer.

А дальше никаких проблем: `$new_Array` - пустой массив.

Comment: теперь понятно )

Comment: можно ли как-то по другому решить данный вопрос???

Comment: Можно. Привел код в ответе.

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "SELECT  `section`, COUNT(*) AS  `count` FROM  `files` WHERE  `game` =  '1' GROUP BY  `section`";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
   echo 'Файлов нет!';
}
else {
   while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
      echo $r["section"] . ' ' . $r["count"] . '<br>';
   }
}
```

Comment: спасибо вам всем, вы мне очень помогли!)

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "SELECT section, count(1) FROM files WHERE game='1' GROUP BY section";
$data = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
foreach ($data as $section => $count)
{
    echo "$section ($count)";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT section, count(section) FROM files WHERE game='1' GROUP BY section

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row[0] , " - ", $row[1];  
}
```

Comment: Опоздал :D

Comment: а как вывести через цикл foreach?